# Gems and C/C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, c, ruby, bundler

I use bundler to manage my gems as every good ruby developer should.  The way I understand it, it ensures that the next developer that checks out my code will install the correct versions of the gems I have installed as part of the project as well as their dependencies.

My question is this.  Every now and then I have to manually install some C or C++ library like ImageMagic, LibXML or IC4U.  Bundler will not do this for me at least on the mac.  I have to do brew install Imagemagick, etc.  That being the case, how can I ensure that the machine in question has the correct C++ library to go with that version of the gem?  Can I install multiple versions of the same library for different projects and point a project that needs one to one folder and another to a different folder?  Or are the C++ libraries generally considered to be backwards compatible indefinitely?

I have only been using linux heavily for a few years and haven't done any C/C++ development so I apologize if this is a rookie question.

Comment: As for “how can I ensure(...)” I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/23745832/2597260 answer can help you.

Comment: The post you sent me to is about Node.js and NPM, not using Ruby with C++

Comment: Yes, it is about Node.js and Ruby’s gems but aside Node.js’ code, the post is relevant. You will face similar problems (for example, does C++’s library works on all Operation Systems?).